# Change Rubinius Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9, rubinius

Is there anyway to change the Ruby version that Rubinius (rbx) uses by default without having to specify the option each time by a flag?:

```
rbx -X19
```

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 ways that you can do this (in ascending order of annoyance).

1. Set an environment variable in directory that you will be calling rbx (like the rails root):

   ```
   export RBXOPT=-X19
   ```

   Note: this will have to be set again if calling rbx from another project.
2. Reinstall Rubinius using rvm specifying the default Ruby version as documented on [rvm.io](https://rvm.io/interpreters/rbx/):

   ```
   rvm reinstall rbx --1.9
   ```

   Note: if rvm complains about bad arguments upgrade it using `rvm get master` or `rvm get stable`
3. Reinstall Rubinius from source specifying which version to use by default as documented on the [Rubinius Blog](http://rubini.us/2011/10/18/contributing-to-rubinius/#language-modes):

   ```
   ./configure --default-version=1.9
   ```

Once you've done this you can check the ruby version Rubinius is using via `rbx -v` (the ruby version is in parenthesis)